# Read and write binary data for both Browser & Node.js?

Tags: binary, buffer, protocols, arraybuffer

Handling binary data (ArrayBuffers and Buffers) without any reader or writer becomes pain because needing to keeping track of the offsets.

I always find myself writing different reader and writer for both browser and node.js part.

Is there any library which would make this easier for browser & node.js project?

I have heard about msgpack and googles protobuf but I think those are overkill as I need to send only integers and rarely strings.

Comment: Possibly develop your own functions. More details are here (I am sure you already know about): https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: The problem is that the same code wouldn't work on browser since Buffer is only in node.js

Comment: That is for a valid reason of security.